# importance of do_build function in bitbake

Tags: bitbake

I am new to bitbake and i am trying to learn it.
I am going through below link for getting a basic understanding
https://a4z.gitlab.io/docs/BitBake/guide.html
Here either through inheritance or directly i see a do_build is always executed.
this might seem a basic question but your answer would really help me.
I read a line like this "build is the task BitBake runs per default if no other task is specified".
Does it mean build is mandatory in bitbake.Is it like main function in c and c+= codes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When no task is specified on the commandline to bitbake, "build" is assumed. This can be overridden with the BB_DEFAULT_TASK variable to some other task. If a task isn't defined and you try and run it, an error will occur that the task can't be found. As such, a build task isn't absolutely required but you will likely run into errors without it in most common usages.